# R/ggplot2: Text annotation cut off when using grid.arrange

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to put multiple ggplot2 graphs onto one page using `grid.arrange`. Each of the plots that I have created have P values added to them as annotations. The annotations display correctly when each plot is created individually, but as soon as I use `grid.arrange`, the text gets cut off as shown below.

Example of single plot

[image]

Using `grid.arrange`

[image]

The code that I used is as follows:

## Example of single plot 1:

```
glennaj<-ggplot(regglen2,aes(N_flex,Seeds))+geom_jitter()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,linetype="dashed",colour="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,101), ylim=c(0,30), expand = c(0,0))+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  geom_text(x=90,y=25,label="R2=0.0038")+
  geom_text(x=90,y=22,label="P=0.4531")
```

## Example of single plot 2:

```
buttlat<-ggplot(regbutt2,aes(Lat,Seeds))+
  geom_jitter()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,linetype="dashed",colour="black")+
  theme_classic()+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(5400,6200), ylim=c(0,22), expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  geom_text(x=6000,y=17,label="R2=0.0380")+
  geom_text(x=6000,y=14,label="P=0.0657")+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1))
```

## Arranging in a grid, using plots previously assigned names as above

```
grid.arrange(glennaj,glencov,glendepth,glenlat,glenlong,tangnaj,
tangcov,tangdepth,tanglat,tanglong,buttnaj,buttcov,buttdepth,buttlat,
buttlong,ncol=5,nrow=3)
```

Comment: can you add a small reproducible example of the two datasets (`regglen2` and `regbutt2`)?

Comment: There is just not enough space! Put fewer plots on a page, or use a smaller font.

Comment: Maybe [turn off clipping](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+ggplot2+turn+off+clipping) in each graph?